# Paint Text Size: universal size for all sizes and images

Tags: android, android-canvas

so I have a bit of a problem here:

My app sets a text to a image view canvas, using paint:

```
textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
textPaint.setTypeface(memeType);
textPaint.setColor(defaultTextColor);
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize); //now 40
```

and then I just draw the text I get from an edittext:

```
canvas.drawText(text, x, y, text);
```

The problem is: the text looks a lot different based on three things: the image size, the screen size and the screen dpi. Therefore, I'm trying to fix those problems to get a one size fits all text size. First, I update the text size depending on the density of the display:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    textSize = size * density;
```

Then I use this function I found on stackOverFlow to get the font size depending on the ratio:

```
    private double getFont(double sizefont, double fontBase, double sizecanvas) {
    double ratio = sizefont / fontBase;
    return sizecanvas * ratio;
}
```

I'm not sure if this function is right tough. As the fontBase I'm using the layout.getWidth, the sizecanvas is the size of the bitmap (and the canvas lol) and the sizefont is the font I want. Now using 40.

On large displays the font looks reaaaaally small and blurry. On small display(5 inches) it looks good.

Does anyone know how should I do it? I'm still working on it and I'll keep you guys updated.

**UPDATE:**

Just to make things clearer:

A font size 40, in the same screen therefore same dpi behaves differently if the images it 800x800 or 1200 x 1200. What I want is the font to behave the same across all my images and different devices. Thanks!

Comment: did you ever solve this problem???

Comment: @gman not really. I've stopped working on the project above to focus in another one. if you solve it please let me know :)